# Passing in parameter to bash script

Tags: bash

I have this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
(echo "AUTH xxx xxx"
sleep 3
number=0161XXXXXXX 
echo "ACTI $number"
sleep 3
echo "SET $number 1 S:$number@x.x.x.x"
sleep 3
echo "STAT $number"
sleep 3
echo "QUIT") | telnet xxx.xxx 777
```

I want to pass the number in as a parameter when I call the script, i.e.

bash number.sh 0161XXXXXXX

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Paste your headline in google and click on first result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [*positional parameters*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html). You could also directly use `$1` instead storing in a variable.

```
#!/bin/sh

arg=$1
(echo "AUTH xxx xxx"
sleep 3
number=$arg
echo "ACTI $number"
sleep 3
echo "SET $number 1 S:$number@x.x.x.x"
sleep 3
echo "STAT $number"
sleep 3
echo "QUIT") | telnet xxx.xxx 777
```

Answer (score 1):

From bash man page:

> Arguments
>
> If arguments remain after option processing, and neither the -c nor
>   the -s option has been supplied, the first argument is assumed to be
>   the name of a file containing shell commands. If bash is invoked in
>   this fashion, $0 is set to the name of the file, and the positional
>   parameters are set to the remaining arguments. Bash reads and executes
>   commands from this file, then exits. Bash's exit status is the exit
>   status of the last command executed in the script. If no commands are
>   executed, the exit status is 0. An attempt is first made to open the
>   file in the current directory, and, if no file is found, then the
>   shell searches the directories in PATH for the script.

So the first argument can be referred as $1, the second as $2 (until $9, if more you need to process it in other way such as using `shift`...)